# How to apply std::regex and std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> to string with non-ascii characters?

Tags: c++, regex

My program receives a very long string as input (it is a part of html code of particular page), partly consisting of non-ascii characters. In this string I need to find some data. Since the 'find by hand' with std::find is too difficult in this case, I tried to use regular expressions. To create and test my regular expression, I used the regex101.com site. There I composed the expression I needed. After making sure that the expected result was obtained, I tried to transfer everything to my c++ programm, but it didn't work for me. Instead of the expected result, I get nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

std::string str ("<ul class=\"update-list\" data-listid=\"3\"><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";10;31;32;35;36;37;63;70;76;81;89;95;103;\" data-createdat=\"1589449592\" title=\"Добавлено в список 14 Май 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/akira\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1618434754.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Акира</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.22</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"104\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";8;14;15;32;36;37;42;63;70;72;76;89;\" data-createdat=\"1600867752\" title=\"Добавлено в список 23 Сен 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/vtorzhenie-gigantov\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1610739780.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Атака Титанов</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.16</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"425\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 9</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";8;14;15;31;32;42;63;70;76;\" data-createdat=\"1600867773\" title=\"Добавлено в список 23 Сен 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/vtorzhenie-gigantov-tv-2\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1613123132.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Атака Титанов 2</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.94</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"2174\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 7</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";8;14;15;42;63;70;76;\" data-createdat=\"1600867788\" title=\"Добавлено в список 23 Сен 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/ataka-titanov-3\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1610739700.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Атака Титанов 3</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.25</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"2613\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 9</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";15;16;32;33;42;43;47;51;86;97;\" data-createdat=\"1617645848\" title=\"Добавлено в список 05 Апр 21:04\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/vedmina-sluzhba-dostavki\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1570963925.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Ведьмина служба доставки</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.12</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"288\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 9</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";8;15;86;98;\" data-createdat=\"1618381750\" title=\"Добавлено в список 14 Апр 09:29\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/vydayushiesya-zveri\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1568753075.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Выдающиеся звери</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.42</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"3619\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 7</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";10;15;18;20;24;31;32;37;63;66;70;74;\" data-createdat=\"1599150486\" title=\"Добавлено в список 03 Сен 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/gangrejv\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1570964080.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Гангрейв</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.14</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"103\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";32;42;54;86;\" data-createdat=\"1592918703\" title=\"Добавлено в список 23 Июн 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/the-borrower-arrietty\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1570967710.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Добывайка Ариэтти</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.95</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"134\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 9</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";15;25;27;36;37;38;63;66;85;89;98;107;\" data-createdat=\"1591343064\" title=\"Добавлено в список 05 Июн 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/evangelion\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1568213365.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Евангелион (ТВ)</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.70</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"409\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";8;15;25;27;36;37;38;63;89;98;\" data-createdat=\"1617299629\" title=\"Добавлено в список 01 Апр 20:53\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/evangelion-po-novomy-film-perviu\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1572174976.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Евангелион 1.0: Ты (не) один</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.43</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";8;15;25;27;36;37;38;43;63;89;98;\" data-createdat=\"1621450083\" title=\"Добавлено в список 19 Май 21:48\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/evangelion-po-novomy-film-vtoroj\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1572175084.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Евангелион 2.0: Ты (не) пройдёшь</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.55</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";8;11;15;25;27;36;37;38;63;89;98;\" data-createdat=\"1621450123\" title=\"Добавлено в список 19 Май 21:48\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/evangelion-po-novomu-film-tretij\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1572175177.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Евангелион 3.0: Ты (не) исправишь</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";15;25;37;63;98;\" data-createdat=\"1629354962\" title=\"Добавлено в список 19 Авг 09:36\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/evangelion-3-0-1-0\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1603731285.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Евангелион: 3.0+1.0</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.71</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"4637\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";10;15;33;37;43;76;\" data-createdat=\"1610916033\" title=\"Добавлено в список 17 Янв 23:40\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/za-oblakami\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/705.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">За облаками</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.09</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";10;14;15;16;21;32;37;40;63;66;\" data-createdat=\"1594834419\" title=\"Добавлено в список 15 Июл 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/kovboy-bibop\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1576936020.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Ковбой Бибоп ТВ</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.39</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"118\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";15;25;27;37;89;98;107;\" data-createdat=\"1591343095\" title=\"Добавлено в список 05 Июн 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/konec-evangeliona\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1572174748.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Конец Евангелиона</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.68</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"1812\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"3\" data-categoryid=\";10;15;16;32;63;\" data-createdat=\"1597318861\" title=\"Добавлено в список 13 Авг 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/lyupen-iii-krov-goemona-isikavy\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1600545713.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Люпен III: Кровь Гоэмона Исикавы</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.66</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"2551\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";8;32;33;36;42;63;64;65;68;80;100;103;\" data-createdat=\"1597767699\" title=\"Добавлено в список 18 Авг 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/manuskript-nindzya\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/82.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Манускрипт ниндзя</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.54</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"82\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";15;32;37;42;63;73;75;76;89;\" data-createdat=\"1592918656\" title=\"Добавлено в список 23 Июн 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/navsikaa-iz-dolini-vetrov\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1570964033.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Навсикая из Долины ветров</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.15</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"201\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";8;15;32;63;67;70;103;\" data-createdat=\"1629946430\" title=\"Добавлено в список 26 Авг 05:53\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/neveroyatnye-priklyucheniya-dzhodzho-tv-2\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1570883716.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Невероятное приключение ДжоДжо: Рыцари звёздной пыли</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.21</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"1490\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 9</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";10;15;36;37;38;63;98;\" data-createdat=\"1596471963\" title=\"Добавлено в список 03 Авг 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/parazit-uchenie-o-zhizni\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1568212642.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Паразит - Учение о жизни</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.22</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"760\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 9</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";10;32;37;74;89;93;\" data-createdat=\"1612558924\" title=\"Добавлено в список 06 Фев 00:02\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/patema-naoborot\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1618437201.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Патэма наоборот</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.00</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"707\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 7</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";15;32;42;63;68;97;\" data-createdat=\"1592918667\" title=\"Добавлено в список 23 Июн 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/princessa-mononoke\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1618437087.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Принцесса Мононоке</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.30</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";8;15;16;32;63;64;68;69;80;\" data-createdat=\"1594834420\" title=\"Добавлено в список 15 Июл 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/samurai-champlu\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1595877866.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Самурай Чамплу</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.24</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"121\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";8;15;32;33;95;\" data-createdat=\"1610831352\" title=\"Добавлено в список 17 Янв 00:09\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/serdcu-hochetsya-krichat\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1618435390.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Сердцу хочется кричать</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.60</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"1502\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 7</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";8;15;16;18;32;42;51;62;63;76;93;\" data-createdat=\"1591343138\" title=\"Добавлено в список 05 Июн 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/stalnoj-alhimik-tv1\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1568209168.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Стальной Алхимик</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.31</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"356\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 9</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"1\" data-categoryid=\";8;15;16;32;42;51;54;63;76;93;\" data-createdat=\"1591343204\" title=\"Добавлено в список 05 Июн 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/stalnoj-alhimik-tv2\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1585340369.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Стальной Алхимик: Братство</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.41</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"370\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";8;15;16;32;42;54;63;76;80;\" data-createdat=\"1591343172\" title=\"Добавлено в список 05 Июн 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/alhimik-film-perviy\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1568163837.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Стальной Алхимик: Фильм Первый - Завоеватель Шамбалы</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.44</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"128\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 9</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";15;33;95;103;\" data-createdat=\"1610868693\" title=\"Добавлено в список 17 Янв 10:31\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/tvoe-imya\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1594741350.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Твоё Имя</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.42</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"1861\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";15;32;42;49;62;103;\" data-createdat=\"1592918689\" title=\"Добавлено в список 23 Июн 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/unesennye-prizrakami\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1570896217.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Унесенные призраками</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.44</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"204\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";8;15;86;95;\" data-createdat=\"1610831321\" title=\"Добавлено в список 17 Янв 00:08\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/forma-golosa\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1562334009.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Форма голоса</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.39</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"2195\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 7</span></div></div></div></a></li><li class=\"profile-list\" data-typeid=\"2\" data-categoryid=\";15;32;33;42;48;72;73;75;93;\" data-createdat=\"1592918676\" title=\"Добавлено в список 23 Июн 2020\"><a href=\"https://yummyanime.club/catalog/item/hodyachiy-zamok\"><img src=\"./Профиль ilya707_files/1570960401.jpg\" class=\"update-img\" loading=\"lazy\"><div class=\"update-list-block\"><div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Ходячий замок</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>9.38</span></div></div></div></a></li></ul>");
std::string str2 = "<div class=\"update-list-flex\"><span class=\"dote\" title=\"Статус: вышел\"></span> <span class=\"update-title\">Акира</span><div class=\"rating-container\"><span title=\"Рейтинг аниме\" class=\"title-rating\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>8.22</span><span title=\"Оценка пользователя\" data-id=\"104\" class=\"user-rating \"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i> 10</span></div></div></div>";

std::vector<std::string> vct;

int main() {
  std::regex rgx("<div class=\"update-list-flex\">([\(\\)a-zA-Z0-9=«»—\\ \\/<>:\"а-яА-Я\\.\\+_;\\-]){0,400}<\\/div><\\/div>");
  std::regex rgx2("<div class=\"update-list-flex\">([\(\)a-zA-Z0-9=«»—\ \/<>:\"а-яА-Яё\.\+_;\-]){0,400}<\/div><\/div>");
    std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> b ( str.begin(), str.end(), rgx ), rend;
    while (b != rend){
        vct.push_back(*b++);
    }

    std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> b2 ( str2.begin(), str2.end(), rgx ), rend2;
    while (b2 != rend2){
      vct.push_back(*b++);
    }

  for(auto & a : vct)
    std::cout << a;
}
```

First string should have 32 matches and the second one is match itself but program outputs nothing. I also was not sure about presence of '' character in expressions so tried to figure it with tests.
Saved expression and test string avaible here:
https://regex101.com/r/pchwHv/2

Comment: I recommend you use *raw string literals* for regexes as it's harder to make escaping errors.

Comment: And maybe you will have better luck with std::wstring and std::wregex

Comment: I don't believe the C++ regex engine is UTF-8 encoding savvy.  If you are using a codepage that has only 8-bit sized characters and no encoding sequences, then it should work.

Comment: 1) The escape sequences must be corrected here, you need to use either raw string literals, or double backslashes before parentheses inside the regex pattern, 2) are you sure there must be `*b++` in `while (b2 != rend2){  vct.push_back(*b++); }`?